# Multiple Tables or multiple fields

Tags: database, cakephp, database-design, relational-database

What would be the best way to do this and why?

Here is a quick look at a part of my database design, I'm looking for the best way to organize this data.

```
"Leads" has many "Students", Leads has many "Contacts"

"Students" belongs to "Leads" and belongs to "People"
   id, person_id, lead_id

"Contacts" belongs to "Leads" and belongs to "People"
   id, person_id, lead_id
```

I want to be able to signify which contact is going to be a "payer" and if a contact would be the primary contact or not.

I thought originally I would add two more tables like this:

```
"PrimaryContacts" belongs to "Contacts"
   id, contact_id
"Payer" belongs to "Contacts"
   id, contact_id
```

Then I realized it seems kind of over kill to add two more tables with something I can easily represent in the initial Contacts table like this

```
"Contacts"
  id, person_id, lead_id, type, payer
```

Then I could have type be 1 or 2, meaning primary or secondary, and then the payer field would be 1 or 2 meaning they either are paying or they aren't.

Is there a benefit of doing it one way or the other or does it matter at all?

Thanks!

Comment: Can there be multiple primary contacts? Is there any interdependence between `type` and `payer` (i.e. are all combinations allowed)? Also, define the word "belongs" - does it signify an N:1 relationship or inheritance (or something else)?

Comment: Only one primary contact per lead.  A contact can be a payer and primary contact or neither or either or so all combinations would be allowed.  Belongs to would signify an N:1 relationship.  Thanks!

Comment: @Brian: Then, you shouldn't say *"PrimaryContacts" **belongs to** "Contacts"*, but *"PrimaryContacts" **are** "Contacts"*

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood N:1.  I'm using cakephp, and in cakephp it is literally belongsTo, hasMany, hasOne etc.  According to CakePHP I define it as belongsTo.  I don't know the generally accepted correct terms.

Comment: @Brian: Sorry, I meant that I understand belongsTo as 1:N relationship. But Contacts to PrimaryContacts looks like a 1:1 relationship - or better a `1::0..1` relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to admit I'm a little confused by your requirements, but interpreting literally what you say seems to lead to the following database model:

[image]

---

The `Contacts.payer` flag enables you to have any number of payers, regardless of their primary status.

There really is no need for a separate `Payer` table in this case.

---

The `Leads.primary_contact_id` is a NULL-able FK towards the `Contacts`, which is what lets you have 0 or 1 primary contact per lead (to avoid the possibility of 0 primary contacts, you'd need a NOT NULL, but this would lead to an insertion cycle, which would have to be resolved through deferred constraints, which are not supported in MySQL).

**However**, this doesn't guarantee that the primary contact belongs to its own lead (i.e. `Contacts.lead_id` could be different from `Leads.lead_id` even when `Contacts.contact_id` matches `Leads.contact_id`). Is that a problem? If yes, you'd need a liberal application of identifying relationships and composite PKs, which could be a problem for ORM.

Separate `PrimaryContacts` table would have a very similar effect to the `Leads.primary_contact_id` (assuming you got your PK right), and would even have the same problem of allowing 0 primary contacts and lead mismatches. Just having a "backward" FK is simpler and more efficient from the database perspective (though I'm not sure if that's still true from the CakePHP perspective).

Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with CakePHP - hopefully you'll be able to "translate" this model there on your own.

Comment: Thank you for your involved answer!  So what would be the negatives of just adding a field "type" for example in the contacts table and setting it to 1 for primary and 2 for secondary?  Is it just that there could then be more than one primary contact per lead?

Comment: @Brian _Is it just that there could then be more than one primary contact per lead?_ Correct.